# How can I scrape nested table using BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Hello everybody and thanks for your help. I am stuck with scraping nested table. I am able to **scrape** the main table, but when I found a table row containing other tables, I do not really know how to proceed. The html table is this one:

```
<tr class="table">
                 <td class="table" valign="top">
                    <p class="tbl-cod">0403</p>
                 </td>
                 <td class="table" valign="top">
                    <p class="tbl-txt">Buttermilk, curdled milk and&nbsp;cream, yoghurt, kephir and other fermented or acidified milk and&nbsp;cream, whether or not concentrated or&nbsp;containing added sugar or other sweetening matter or flavoured or&nbsp;containing added fruit, nuts or&nbsp;cocoa</p>
                 </td>
                 <td class="table" valign="top">
                    <p class="tbl-txt">Manufacture in which:</p>
                    <table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
                       <colgroup><col width="4%">
                       <col width="96%">
                       </colgroup><tbody>
                          <tr>
                             <td valign="top">
                                <p class="normal">—</p>
                             </td>
                             <td valign="top">
                                <p class="normal">all the materials of Chapter&nbsp;4 used are wholly obtained,</p>
                             </td>
                          </tr>
                       </tbody>
                    </table>
                    <table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
                       <colgroup><col width="4%">
                       <col width="96%">
                       </colgroup><tbody>
                          <tr>
                             <td valign="top">
                                <p class="normal">—</p>
                             </td>
                             <td valign="top">
                                <p class="normal">all the fruit juice (except that of pineapple, lime or&nbsp;grapefruit) of heading&nbsp;2009 used is originating,</p>
                                <p class="normal">and</p>
                             </td>
                          </tr>
                       </tbody>
                    </table>
                    <table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
                       <colgroup><col width="4%">
                       <col width="96%">
                       </colgroup><tbody>
                          <tr>
                             <td valign="top">
                                <p class="normal">—</p>
                             </td>
                             <td valign="top">
                                <p class="normal">the value of all the materials of Chapter&nbsp;17 used does not exceed 30&nbsp;% of the ex-works price of the product</p>
                             </td>
                          </tr>
                       </tbody>
                    </table>
                 </td>
                 <td class="table" valign="top">
                    <p class="normal">&nbsp;</p>
                 </td>
              </tr>
```

I scraped the main table using this code:

```py
with open ('algeriaroo.txt', 'w') as algroo:
    for row in RoOtbody.find_all('tr'):
        for cell in row.find_all('td'):
            algroo.write(cell.text.strip())
        algroo.write('\n')
```

So far, I obtained this kind of scraping:

```
0403Buttermilk, curdled milk and cream, yoghurt, kephir and other fermented or acidified milk and cream, whether or not concentrated or containing added sugar or other sweetening matter or flavoured or containing added fruit, nuts or cocoaManufacture in which:






—


all the materials of Chapter 4 used are wholly obtained,










—


all the fruit juice (except that of pineapple, lime or grapefruit) of heading 2009 used is originating,
and










—


the value of all the materials of Chapter 17 used does not exceed 30 % of the ex-works price of the product—all the materials of Chapter 4 used are wholly obtained,—all the fruit juice (except that of pineapple, lime or grapefruit) of heading 2009 used is originating,
and—the value of all the materials of Chapter 17 used does not exceed 30 % of the ex-works price of the product
—all the materials of Chapter 4 used are wholly obtained,
—all the fruit juice (except that of pineapple, lime or grapefruit) of heading 2009 used is originating,
and
—the value of all the materials of Chapter 17 used does not exceed 30 % of the ex-works price of the product
```

I'd like to scrape something like this:

> 0403Buttermilk, curdled milk and cream, yoghurt, kephir and other
> fermented or acidified milk and cream, whether or not concentrated
> or containing added sugar or other sweetening matter or flavoured
> or containing added fruit, nuts or cocoaManufacture in which: — all
> the materials of Chapter 4 used are wholly obtained, — all the fruit
> juice (except that of pineapple, lime or grapefruit) of heading 2009
> used is originating, and — the value of all the materials of
> Chapter 17 used does not exceed 30 % of the ex-works price of the
> product

Thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You are searching probably for `.get_text()` method with `separator=` parameter.

For example (`html_code` contains html code from your question):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_code, 'html.parser')
print(soup.select_one('tr.table').get_text(strip=True, separator=' '))
```

Prints:

> 0403 Buttermilk, curdled milk and cream, yoghurt, kephir and other
>   fermented or acidified milk and cream, whether or not concentrated
>   or containing added sugar or other sweetening matter or flavoured
>   or containing added fruit, nuts or cocoa Manufacture in which: — all
>   the materials of Chapter 4 used are wholly obtained, — all the fruit
>   juice (except that of pineapple, lime or grapefruit) of heading 2009
>   used is originating, and — the value of all the materials of
>   Chapter 17 used does not exceed 30 % of the ex-works price of the
>   product

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Just, I'm not sure I understand what `soup.select_one('tr.table')` does.

Comment: @AleVesprini `select_one('tr.table')` is CSS selector -> select tag `<tr>` with `class=table`. You can also write `soup.find('tr', {'class':'table'}).get_text(strip=True, separator=' ')`, it's equal.

Comment: should I put it in the second for cycle? I am afraid that I will get a conflict when scraping the main table

Comment: @AleVesprini The two methods - `select_one()` with CSS selector and `bs4` `find()` are equal here. So when one breaks, the other breaks too. If you want to be sure, put some checks in your code and handle error conditions.

Comment: How can I use either method to put what I scrap into a text file? I tried to adapt your suggestion this way:  `with open ('algeriaroo2.txt', 'w') as algroo:
    for row in RoOtbody.select_one('tr.table'):
        algroo.get_text(strip=True, separator=' ')` because I need to put every `<tr>` in the file, not only the nested table. This is just one of the several nested tables I need to scrap. I just wrote the first one for the sake of semplicity. Sadly, I cannot make `print()` to work with my goals

Answer (score 0):

Just a suggestion.
Logic to extract data from tables can be added in function. Check for each td if 
it has  tag and if present call the same function with 
The only issue is return value may be create a dict and return to calling function and process it.
This will help for any number of nested tables.